# Cannot use curl even though git is installed

Tags: windows, git, curl, github, cmd

I have `git for windows` installed, but I can't run `curl` commands in cmd. If I type in `curl`, I get the following error:

```
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: For windows system, try `git bash.exe`, and try `curl` in that cli.

Comment: @DavidGuan bash.exe isn't a git command

Comment: Sorry, I mean the exe file, with git's logo, I forgot the exact name.

Comment: @DavidGuan You had it right, it's named "Git Bash", and should appear in the programs list in the start menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is normally included in the Git package for Windows.
If you start "Git Bash", the command "curl" should be available in your bash window.
The curl executable is located in the "bin" directory, along with all the other applications installed with git.